# How can insert a javascript script on database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a javascript script and Im trying to insert it on databse than echo on the screen.

I tried:

```
$script = base64_encode( $script  );



 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO myscripts (ID,script) 
 VALUES (419,'{$script}')");

 echo stripslashes( base64_decode( $row["script"] ) ) ;
```

When It prints on the screen, i get erros:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: You are only base 64 encoding before insert but on retrieval you're base 64 decoding _and_ stripping the slashes.

Comment: which line give thoses errores?

Comment: print out the sql query to see how the syntax is getting messed up

Comment: @developerwjk The error is from Javascript, not MySQL.

Comment: As @Vld Suggests, you should not remove slashes from Javascript, they're valid characters.

Comment: Why `base64_encode`?

Comment: @RobertRocha maybe he did not discovered `mysqli_real_escape` yet, not a bad idea tho!